# Create Job for running procedure with variable

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I´m try to create a JOB whit this form:

```
BEGIN
  SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB
    (
       job_name        => 'OWNER.TEST_PROM'
      ,start_date      => TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2018/12/07 03:00:00.324000 -05:00','yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss.ff tzh:tzm')
      ,repeat_interval => 'freq=daily'
      ,end_date        => NULL
      ,job_class       => 'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS'
      ,job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK'
    ,job_action      => ' 

    BEGIN 

    DECLARE

    VAR_1    VARCHAR2(30) := '001';
    VAR_2    VARCHAR2(20) := '';
    VAR_3    VARCHAR2(20) := TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SYSDATE-15),''YYYYMMDD'');
    VAR_4    VARCHAR2(20) := TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SYSDATE),''YYYYMMDD'');    

    OWNER.LOAD_DATA_LOCAL.LOAD_PROM          (VAR_1,VAR_2,VAR_3,VAR_4); 
    OWNER.LOAD_DATA_LOCAL.LOAD_COB_PROM      (VAR_1,VAR_2,VAR_3,VAR_4);
    OWNER.LOAD_DATA_LOCAL.LOAD_CUP           (VAR_1,VAR_2,VAR_3,VAR_4); 
    end;'
    ,comments        => 'Ejecuta LOAD_prueba_cupones'
    );
end;
/
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
Error at line 1
ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 185
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 486
ORA-06512: at line 2

Script Terminated on line 1.
```

Comment: Your anonymous block is invalid. The BEGIN keyword should follow the end of the DECLARE section.

Answer (score 2):

The `job_action` declaration is enclosed in single quotes. Hence, you need to escape all single quotes that are within it, else Oracle is not able to properly parse it.

So you should replace every `'` with `''` within the `job_action`, namely in the declarations of `VAR1` and `VAR2` (`VAR3` and `VAR4` are fine already) :

```
BEGIN
  SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB
    (
       job_name        => 'OWNER.TEST_PROM'
      ,start_date      => TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2018/12/07 03:00:00.324000 -05:00','yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss.ff tzh:tzm')
      ,repeat_interval => 'freq=daily'
      ,end_date        => NULL
      ,job_class       => 'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS'
      ,job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK'
    ,job_action      => ' 

    BEGIN 

    DECLARE

    VAR_1    VARCHAR2(30) := ''001'';
    VAR_2    VARCHAR2(20) := '''';
    VAR_3    VARCHAR2(20) := TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SYSDATE-15),''YYYYMMDD'');
    VAR_4    VARCHAR2(20) := TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SYSDATE),''YYYYMMDD'');    

    OWNER.LOAD_DATA_LOCAL.LOAD_PROM          (VAR_1,VAR_2,VAR_3,VAR_4); 
    OWNER.LOAD_DATA_LOCAL.LOAD_COB_PROM      (VAR_1,VAR_2,VAR_3,VAR_4);
    OWNER.LOAD_DATA_LOCAL.LOAD_CUP           (VAR_1,VAR_2,VAR_3,VAR_4); 
    end;'
    ,comments        => 'Ejecuta LOAD_prueba_cupones'
    );
end;
/
```

See [this Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schedadmin006.htm#i1009099) for examples of creating jobs.

Answer (score 2):

Or use the Oracle quoting string construct q'[ ... ]' and do not worry about the number of escape quotes:

```
 BEGIN
  SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB
    (
       job_name        => 'OWNER.TEST_PROM'
      ,start_date      => TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2018/12/07 03:00:00.324000 -05:00','yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss.ff tzh:tzm')
      ,repeat_interval => 'freq=daily'
      ,end_date        => NULL
      ,job_class       => 'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS'
      ,job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK'
    ,job_action      => q'[ 

    BEGIN 

    DECLARE

    VAR_1    VARCHAR2(30) := '001';
    VAR_2    VARCHAR2(20) := '';
    VAR_3    VARCHAR2(20) := TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SYSDATE-15),'YYYYMMDD');
    VAR_4    VARCHAR2(20) := TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SYSDATE),'YYYYMMDD');    

    OWNER.LOAD_DATA_LOCAL.LOAD_PROM          (VAR_1,VAR_2,VAR_3,VAR_4); 
    OWNER.LOAD_DATA_LOCAL.LOAD_COB_PROM      (VAR_1,VAR_2,VAR_3,VAR_4);
    OWNER.LOAD_DATA_LOCAL.LOAD_CUP           (VAR_1,VAR_2,VAR_3,VAR_4); 
    end;]'
    ,comments        => 'Ejecuta LOAD_prueba_cupones'
    );
end;
/
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
BEGIN 

DECLARE

VAR_1    VARCHAR2(30) := '001';
VAR_2    VARCHAR2(20) := '';
VAR_3    VARCHAR2(20) := TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SYSDATE-15),'YYYYMMDD');
VAR_4    VARCHAR2(20) := TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SYSDATE),'YYYYMMDD');    

begin
OWNER.LOAD_DATA_LOCAL.LOAD_PROM          (VAR_1,VAR_2,VAR_3,VAR_4); 
OWNER.LOAD_DATA_LOCAL.LOAD_COB_PROM      (VAR_1,VAR_2,VAR_3,VAR_4);
OWNER.LOAD_DATA_LOCAL.LOAD_CUP           (VAR_1,VAR_2,VAR_3,VAR_4); 
end;
--comments        => 'Ejecuta LOAD_prueba_cupones'
--);

end;
```

I'm guessing here because I have no way of testing the code, but there seemed to be some syntactical errors at first glance.